# The hull of the tank must not turn with the turret

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a tank that has a script hanging on it that moves and rotates it: "MainTankEngine". And there is also a script that rotates the tower along the "Y" axis behind the camera.

That's the problem, when I turn the tank on the "A" and "D" buttons, the turret rotates along with the hull and its coordinates change, and the gun stays in place and rotates behind the camera from where it stopped when the hull was rotated.

I need to make the tank's turret move back when the hull is rotated. Or at least so that when the hull turns, the tank turret remains where it was before the hull began to turn.

Tank movement script:

```
using UnityEngine;

//Script that moves and rotates the tank
public class MainTankEngine : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float speed = 10f;
   public float rotateSpeed = 10f;

   Rigidbody rb;

   public static float verticalMove;
   public static float rotateMove;

   private void Start()
   {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
   }

   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
      Move();
      Rotate();
   }

   void Move()
   {
      verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
      Vector3 moveVertical = transform.forward * verticalMove * speed * Time.deltaTime;
      rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVertical);
   }

   void Rotate()
   {
      rotateMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
      if (verticalMove < 0)
         rotateMove *= -1f;
      Quaternion moveRotate = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotateMove, 0f);
      rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * moveRotate);
   }
}
```

Turret rotation script:

```
using UnityEngine;

//Script that rotates the tower along the "Y" axis behind the camera
public class TowerRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Transform cam;
   public float speed = 50f;

   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
      transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, cam.eulerAngles.y , 0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
   }
}
```

Link to video: https://youtu.be/Bh8hEGn1J8s

Comment: If I replace "localRotation" with "rotation" in the turret script, then the turret rotation works as it should, but now when I run into something, the turret does not change along the "X" and "Z" axes and remains flat, as if it does not belong to the body.

Answer (score 0):

So I haven't tested the code, but this should do the trick. Most steps are commented, so even if something is off you should be able to adapt it to work.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var globalCameraForward = cam.forward;

    var localCameraForward = transform.InverseTransformDirection(globalCameraForward); // transform the global forward vector to local space of the turret
    
    var restrictedLocalCameraForward = localCameraForward;
    restrictedLocalCameraForward.y = 0f; // restrict the local forward vector to the XZ plane

    var lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(localCameraForward); // this is the LOCAL rotation that the turret should be looking at

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, lookRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime); 
}
```

Comment: I did not change the code, everything seems to be correct. But the tower is completely crazy and does not turn on other axes

Comment: it's supposed to "not turn on other axes" right? Otherwise you can send the project and I can have a look.

Comment: Like this:
https://youtu.be/Pbe5GEXkEPU

Comment: How does it look if you change the last line to `transform.localRotation = lookRotation;`? Otherwise I'll need your project to help.